# How to change the topic_name string to PROGMEM?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, library

I'm trying to save SRAM on my Arduino pro mini by going through some libraries. I've noticed that to use my Arduino as a ROS node the library stores the topic name and message type as constants.

```
class Publisher
{
public:
  Publisher( const char * topic_name, Msg * msg, int    endpoint=rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo::ID_PUBLISHER) :
    topic_(topic_name), 
    msg_(msg),
    endpoint_(endpoint) {};

  int publish( const Msg * msg ) { return nh_->publish(id_, msg); };
  int getEndpointType(){ return endpoint_; }

  const char * topic_;
  Msg *msg_;
  // id_ and no_ are set by NodeHandle when we advertise 
  int id_;
  NodeHandleBase_* nh_;

private:
  int endpoint_;
};
```

How can I store the constants to PROGMEM? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that you cannot save more memory on `topic-name` nor `msg` parameters. Their memory usage is already optimized.

The `const` keyword in the constructor declaration `Publisher( const char * topic_name, Msg * msg, ...` just tells the compiler that the parameter won't be changed throughout their life cycle. But their values will be defined at run-time during object creation when you issue something like this:

```
Publisher pb = new Publisher("topic", "message", ...);
```

So, they cannot be put into flash memory if they are not there already. But if the strings you pass on to the constructor are already in flash, then you're already saving those bits of RAM.

---

<sub>Finally, I just wanted to warn you not to modify 3rd party lib code extensively without comprehensive testing, like you are trying to do. You'll start to get strange behavior in your code. The slightest and simplest of changes may have unforeseen consequences.</sub>